# spring sytem properties issue

Tags: java, spring

I have below bean it creates properties object.

```
<bean id="commonProps"
        class="com.test.TestPropertiesBean">
        <property name="commonProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="log4jFile">./config/log4j.xml</prop>
                <prop key="directory">/config</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

after loading the above bean, if i set system properties, say `System.setProperty("threshold","true");` threshold becomes null.

Is there any problem to set system property after creating properties object in spring?.if i create system.setproperty just before loading the above bean  it works perfectly.

Comment: I think we are missing some context here.

Comment: Hi,What context we missed?

Comment: What does the `threshold` property have to do with the bean you've shown us? Also what do you mean it becomes `null`?

Comment: value becomes null for string "threshold",when i try to retrieve it using System.getProperty("threshold")

Comment: what mean is,if i set any system variables, those values become null

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about. Please show the `TestPropertiesBean` class.